# Custom Data not appearing on Event Info and Settings form

Tags: custom-fields

We recently migrated our Drupal/CiviCRM site to a new server, and the oddest thing: on the Event Info and Settings form, no custom field data is appearing on the form. Some details:

- The data is in the database, and it appears on the public view of the events.
- If we add data to these custom fields and submit, it works as expected - data goes in and appears on the front end - but it still doesn't show on the Info and Settings form.
- Clicking save on the Info and Settings form submits it blank, so it removes any data on those fields.
- All the other forms look fine and show custom data in the normal way.
- The custom data will show up using the API Explorer
- This was working fine on our previous server
- Nothing appears in the browser console or the Civi logs
- There is a maybe related thing in the Drupal log (I'll include at the end)
- Version of Civi and Drupal did not change from old server to new server (Drupal 9.5.11 Civi 5.66)
- PHP changed from 7.4 to 8.1 (but the form is working as expected on local environment with 8.1)
- Server OS was Amazon Linux 2 is now Ubuntu 22.04 (can't see how this matters, but we're lost at this point)

Any suggested things to look at would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the Drupal log that might be relevant:

```
https://staging.website|https://staging.website/civicrm/custom?action=2&cgcount=1&qf=CRMEventFormManageEventEventInfo1r1n0qwlqzb4w4wc4cgscs4kcgkg0sc8g4gsw8k0skw8s4kg8g_1833&snippet=json&subType=7&type=Event|https://staging.website/civicrm/event/manage/settings?reset=1&action=update&id=391|25401||Warning: Undefined array key "prefix" in include() (line 11 of /var/www/website/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%B2/B2F/B2F0EF90%%ContactReference.tpl.php) #0 /var/www/website/web/core/includes/bootstrap.inc(347): _drupal_error_handler_real()
#1 /var/www/website/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%B2/B2F/B2F0EF90%%ContactReference.tpl.php(11): _drupal_error_handler()
#2 /var/www/website/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(1914): include('...')
#3 /var/www/website/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%1D/1DB/1DB03A28%%CustomField.tpl.php(103): Smarty->_smarty_include()
#4 /var/www/website/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(1914): include('...')
#5 /var/www/website/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%AC/AC7/AC7FEABB%%CustomData.tpl.php(33): Smarty->_smarty_include()
#6 /var/www/website/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(1914): include('...')
#7 /var/www/website/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%0B/0B8/0B84C601%%CustomData.tpl.php(35): Smarty->_smarty_include()
#8 /var/www/website/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(1914): include('...')
#9 /var/www/website/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%22/223/2235C464%%CustomDataByType.tpl.php(6): Smarty->_smarty_include()
#10 /var/www/website/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(1914): include('...')
#11 /var/www/website/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%0C/0CB/0CBEC124%%default.tpl.php(19): Smarty->_smarty_include()
#12 /var/www/website/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(1914): include('...')
#13 /var/www/website/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%A0/A0D/A0D7E591%%snippet.tpl.php(26): Smarty->_smarty_include()
#14 /var/www/website/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(1273): include('...')
#15 /var/www/website/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Smarty.php(205): Smarty->fetch()
#16 /var/www/website/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(117): CRM_Core_Smarty->fetch()
#17 /var/www/website/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(83): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->renderForm()
#18 /var/www/website/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform()
#19 /var/www/website/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle()
#20 /var/www/website/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Controller.php(355): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle()
#21 /var/www/website/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(98): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#22 /var/www/website/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(295): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run()
#23 /var/www/website/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem()
#24 /var/www/website/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke()
#25 /var/www/website/web/modules/contrib/civicrm/src/Civicrm.php(88): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke()
#26 /var/www/website/web/modules/contrib/civicrm/src/Controller/CivicrmController.php(83): Drupal\civicrm\Civicrm->invoke()
#27 [internal function]: Drupal\civicrm\Controller\CivicrmController->main()
#28 /var/www/website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(123): call_user_func_array()
#29 /var/www/website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(580): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
#30 /var/www/website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(124): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext()
#31 /var/www/website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(97): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext()
#32 /var/www/website/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(169): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
#33 /var/www/website/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(81): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw()
#34 /var/www/website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(58): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle()
#35 /var/www/website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(48): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle()
#36 /var/www/website/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(106): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle()
#37 /var/www/website/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(85): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass()
#38 /var/www/website/web/core/modules/ban/src/BanMiddleware.php(50): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle()
#39 /var/www/website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(48): Drupal\ban\BanMiddleware->handle()
#40 /var/www/website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(51): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle()
#41 /var/www/website/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle()
#42 /var/www/website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(718): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle()
#43 /var/www/website/web/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle()
#44 {main}.
```

Comment: Looks like there was already a patch for this it just took some digging to find: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4706